# Youtube API for iOS no longer support Landscape since iOS 10?

Tags: iphone, youtube, youtube-api, ios10, screen-rotation

I'm using YTPlayerView Youtube API to support videos in my app.

Until the release of iOS10, my app was correctly switching the video to landscape when the video was playing full screen and rotating the device.

Since I upgraded to iOS10, the video no longer rotates with the device, this can be reproduced in the simulator (working with iOS 9, no longer working with iOS 10).

My app only supports Portrait mode, but I was able to switch full screen videos to landscape when playing full screen.

Any tip ?
Thanks

Comment: I think only a Googler can answer you with that. I don't see any updated revision regarding that problem that you can see in the [Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history) and [IOS Helper](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper#best-practices-and-limitations). If you think this is a bug, then try to [file a ticket](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list?q=label:APi-YouTube) about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the way the orientation mode is treated in iOS 10 you have the following options:

**"Politically"-correct solution**

1) allow your app to be in all the orientation modes in the info.plist

2) disallow the landscape everywhere else

**The hacky solution**

Your AppDelegate gets called every time you rotate your phone regarding the supported orientations for the specific window. So if you can detect that the view controller inside the "current window" is the youtubevideo view controller, then you can return all orientations, otherwise return portret.

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    guard let topController = window?.topController() else {
      return application.supportedInterfaceOrientations(for: window)
    }

    let className = NSStringFromClass(type(of: topController))
    let hackyViewControllers = ["avfullscreenviewcontroller"]

    if hackyViewControllers.contains(className.lowercased()) {
      return .allButUpsideDown
    } else {
      return .portrait
    }
  }
```

** as you can see we check for AVFullScreenViewController which is exactly the UIViewController subclass responsible for displaying youtube videos in full screen.